# Как вписать значение атрибута name в переменную?

Tags: php, html

В зависимости на какую кнопку нажмет пользователь, с таким и значением атрибута name отправится форма. Как вписать значение атрибута name в переменную, если значение в ней может оказаться разным?

```
<input name="Сухари" type="submit" value="Заказать сухари" />
<input name="Чипсы" type="submit" value="Заказать чипсы" />
```

Как мне слово "Сухари" при нажатии вписать в переменную $zakaz и если я нажму на слово "Чипсы", вписать в переменную $zakaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При отправке формы отправляется name того submit'а, который был нажат. То есть, в вашем случае нужна проверка

```
if(isset($_POST['Сухари']))
{
    //используем $_POST['Сухари_value']
}
elseif(isset($_POST['Чипсы']))
{
    //используем $_POST['Чипсы_value']
}
```

Но вообще, не советую называть переменные кириллицей.

Comment: если утф-8, имхо, без разницы как называть )

Answer (score 1):

Для отправки данных на сервер в вашем html-коде должна быть форма или это должен обрабатывать JavaScript, отдавая данные асинхронно!

```
<form name="zakaz_form" method="post" action="path\to_script.php">
<input name="suhari" ...>
<input name="chips" ...>
</form>
```

А уже в скрипте у переменной с именем $_POST['suhari'] будет нужное значение, если нажмете на кнопочку.

Answer (score 1):

Помните, что ИЕ не позволяет манипулировать атрибутом name в форме, чтобы изменить атрибут вам надо спрятать старый инпут и создать новый с новыми атрибутами. Может Вам лучше сделать чекбокс "Заказать сухари/чипсы" и в зависимости какой выбран показывать соответствующий input с нужным атрибутом name?